# Event Binding between XAML elements

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbox1" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbox2" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub txtbox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles txtbox1.GotFocus
    txtbox2.Text = "Hello"
End Sub
End Class
```

The codes above work great.

My question:

I want same action using only XAML element binding.

In other words I dont want using vb.net from code behind.

Comment: Short answer - no can do. And what exactly "_XAML_ binding" means? I assume you mean a regular binding which can be expressed in _XAML_ language. In this kind of scenarios the usual way to solve the problem is to either use attached properties or behaviors (which in fact also rely on attached properties).

Comment: Are you looking for a command in a viewmodel (or similar) to execute the event code?

Comment: @JorgeY. Any solution is okey for me wihout using Code Behind.

Comment: The only "solution" that does not require code-behind I can think of is finding a 3rd party library that happens to just meet your requirements in 100%. And I don't know any that would do exactly that. Your best bet would be a trigger (in this particular case) that is able to one-time set a property value in response to an event. Perhaps _MVVMLight_ does have such one, but I wouldn't count on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataTrigger on the IsFocused or IsKeyboardFocused property of txtbox1 should work:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbox1" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txtbox2" Height="30" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=txtbox1}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Hello"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.